# TableView технический вопрос работы с коллекцией JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, tableview

Всем привет! У меня есть коллекция:

```
 ObservableList<Product> productList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

и таблица  `TableView table=new TableView<>();`  с двумя столбцами:

```
TableColumn nameOfProdCol=new TableColumn("Наименование товара");
TableColumn priseOfProdCol=new TableColumn("Цена товара");
```

Как поместить в столбцы соответствующие данные?

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part2/ вот хороший туториал

Comment: @МихаилКетов Видел, на данный момент необходимо сделать без fxml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё проще, чем я думал.

1. Установить generic для таблицы. В нем указать тип, с которым мы будем работать, в моем случае это:

   `TableView<`**Product**`> table=new TableView<>();`
2. В колонках нужно установить generic с двумя параметрами: первый из которых- тип generic, что и в таблице, а второй- совпадающей с типом поля "Наименование товара". 
   В моем случае нужно поменять

   До:

   `TableColumn nameOfProdCol=new TableColumn("Наименование товара");`

   После:

   TableColumn nameOfProdCol=new TableColumn("Наименование товара");
3. Привязать ИМЯ поля, с которым будем работать в колонке:

   `//public class Product {//используемый тип в коллекции и самой таблице

   //private String` **name**`=null; //продукция
   //...
   //}`

   `nameOfProdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("`**name**`"));`

   //4. Добавляем коллекцию в таблицу и..

   `table.setItems(productList);`

Готово!